# How to access the value of a variable inside the body of a function of class A in class B?

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, xcode8

Basically I want to use the variable 'userID' to in the function(in class SignUpPage.swift) to call it **HERE** which is in ViewController.swift class.

ref.child("Users").child(**HERE**).setValue(["First Name": userFN, "Last Name": userLN])

I have tried making userID a global variable too, but that's a no go too.
Here is the whole code:

```
class SignUpPage: UIViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!



@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: Any) {


    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in


        if error != nil{

            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I want to use this variable(userID) in the ViewController.swift class so that I can save FirstName, LastName, EmailID and Password under the same token.

```
        let userID = user!.uid

        let userEmail = self.emailField.text!
        let userPassword = self.passwordField.text!

        self.ref.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(["User Email": userEmail, "User Password": userPassword])
    })

}
```

}

**ViewController.swift class**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

var ID = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBOutlet weak var fnField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lnField: UITextField!

@IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: Any) {



    let userFN: String = fnField.text!
    let userLN: String = lnField.text!

    ref.child("Users").child(**HERE**).setValue(["First Name": userFN, "Last Name": userLN])

}
```

}

Comment: How are you presenting ViewController from Signup ViewController?

Comment: Looks like `child()` takes a String. What is the type of `userID`?

Comment: @gkchristopher Yeah, child() takes a string
userID is also of String type

The problem I'm having is in accessing the variable userID outside its class

Comment: @SahanaKini I've used a simple action segue

Comment: You will need some way to get the data back to `ViewController`. Perhaps create a delegate or set a closure on `SignUpPage` to run when you have data back.

Comment: Have you tried passing the userid from SignupViewController to ViewController in prepareForSegue? Reference http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Comment: @SahanaKini yeah I did. I tried printing the value in the console after the segue to confirm, but it's giving out a nil valye

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this is basic auth logic, so why don't you save userId in UserDefaults,

```
let userID = user!.uid
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.set(userID, forKey: "userID")
```

Than anywhere when you want to get stored userID,

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let userID  = userDefaults.string(forKey: "userID")
ref.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(["First Name": userFN, "Last Name": userLN])
```

Comment: It's giving an error in this line 

       let userID = userDefault.string(forKey: "userID")! as String

The error reads

 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_I368_INVOP, subcode =0x0)

Comment: that should be let userID = userDefault.string(forKey: "userID") as! String

Comment: I tried that but it's giving an error, saying - downcast from 'String?' to String only unwraps optionals

Comment: that's my bad, userDefaults.string() returns a string, so you don't need to downcast. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This worked, partially. Now the first and last names are getting stored but email ID and password are not getting stored in the database :/

Comment: @AkshayYerneni, it's a firebase issue, sorry I'm not familiar with firebase auth, you should ask a new question about it, sure so users will help you.